# How can I make PHP #[attribute(var: 'string')] fully gray include parameters?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In `settings.json` I added a `editor.tokenColorCustomization`:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "meta.attribute.php"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#464646"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But brackets, parameters and its values not grayed out. How can I colorize tags from `#[` to `]` fully?

[image: grayed PHP attribute tags]

Here's some code so you can try tinkering with it yourself:

```php
<?php
class SomeClass
{
   #[ORM\Id]
   #[Orm\Column(type: 'integer')]
   private ?int $id = null;

   #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
   private ?string $some = null;
}
php?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like deeper TextMate scope patterns are matching inside what matches for the `meta.attribute.php` scope selector.

I tried to get around this by writing a [descendant selector](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors#descendant_selectors) using a wildcard like `"meta.attribute.php *"`, but found out that VS Code doesn't support the TextMate scope wildcard selector at the time of this writing (see [Textmate scope selectors: wildcard * support #160](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate/issues/160)).

Using `"meta.attribute.php source.php"` also didn't work as I'd hoped, nor did adding more `source.php` to the end of that.

At least for the code that you've shown, you can do the following:

```json
"scope": [
    "meta.attribute.php",
    "meta.attribute.php string.quoted.single.php",
    "meta.attribute.php constant.numeric.decimal.php",
],
```

And extend it as needed. The Scope Inspector is useful (`Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the command palette). Yeah, not very ideal, but I couldn't find better.

As for the bracket colourization, that's coming from the bracket-pair colourization feature, which you can disable with `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false`. I don't know of a way to disable it only inside PHP attributes.